# docker-compose shared volumes between service

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I would like to shared files from one service to an other.
I make a short exemple.

- Docker-compose.yml
- mobile:

  - dockerfile
  - app.apk
- web:

  - dockerfile

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:
  web:
    build: ./web
    depends_on: 
      - mobile
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/shared

  mobile:
    build: ./mobile
    volumes:
      - data-volume:/var/lib/shared

volumes:
  data-volume:
```

Dockerfile.yml (mobile)

```
FROM node:alpine AS mobile

COPY app.apk /var/lib/shared

RUN ls /var/lib/shared
```

Dockerfile.yml (web)

```
FROM node:alpine AS web

RUN ls /var/lib/shared
```

So I want to see app.apk from mobile service in web service.

I try to use volumes in docker-compose but it's not working. I have tried to figure out for hours.

Someone know how to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the dockerfile is executed first. The compose-file then overrides the shared folder. You can't access volumes in dockerfiles.

- When you first built the docker-container, your `app.apk` gets copied into the docker-image.
- Then compose starts the container and mounts the new (and probably empty) folder to `/var/lib/shared`.
- Then the old content of /var/lib/shared is "overshadowed" by the new content and you can't access the old content anymore.

**solution**: copy the app into the volume after starting the container.

using `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` you can start a shell in the container after it has started. You can find the name with `docker ps`.

Comment: Ok and how I wait until the container has started before to copy my app ?

Comment: using `docker exec -it <container_name> bash` you can start a shell in the container after it has started. You can find the name with `docker ps`.

Comment: Ok but it's a school project and I can only use docker-compose build and docker-compose up. Do you have an idea with that ?

Comment: the command in `RUN` is executed after the volume is mounted. You can use that to copy stuff into the volume with cp for example. (This is very hacky and I don't recommend it in any other setting)

Comment: wait, I made a mistake. you need `CMD` and not `RUN` for this

Comment: This suggestion is not helpful as it does not demonstrate updates to docker-compose file to achieve the result. It is suggesting manually copying the file outside of docker-compose